# trying to convert rgb from a .net Color to a string such as "red" or "blue"

Tags: c#, .net, image, colors, system.drawing.color

All of my methods are failing me in various ways.
different lighting can mess it all up too.

has anyone every trying to return a name given a rgb value? "red" "green" "blue" would be enough to satisfy my needs for today.

i have unsafe byte processing of images from my web cam.

[image: webcam]

[image: colors]

Comment: So the problem could be restated as given a dictionary of colors and names, for a given color find the name of the nearest color?

Answer (score 5):

If you have a list of known colors with names, you can see which of those known colors a given target color is 'closest' to, using a 'closeness' function along the lines of (F# code):

```
let Diff (c1:Color) (c2:Color) =
    let dr = (c1.R - c2.R) |> int
    let dg = (c1.G - c2.G) |> int
    let db = (c1.B - c2.B) |> int
    dr*dr + dg*dg + db*db
```

Whichever one of the known colors has the smallest diff to the target color you want to name, use that name.

Comment: alto a pretty piece of code.

this solution just gives you the max. of the rgbs difference.  not really what im asking.  

i want to give a color and find close. but writing this i answered it in my head. i will post code later

Answer (score 3):

You can try this code

```
static char[] hexDigits = {
         '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7',
         '8', '9', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'};



public static string ColorToHexString(Color color)
        {
            byte[] bytes = new byte[4];
            bytes[0] = color.A;
            bytes[1] = color.R;
            bytes[2] = color.G;
            bytes[3] = color.B;
            char[] chars = new char[bytes.Length * 2];
            for (int i = 0; i < bytes.Length; i++)
            {
                int b = bytes[i];
                chars[i * 2] = hexDigits[b >> 4];
                chars[i * 2 + 1] = hexDigits[b & 0xF];
            }
            return new string(chars);
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

I personally find it more natural to think of colors in terms of [hue/saturation/brightness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSV_color_space) than RGB values, and I think that would work well for you in this case. Try this:

Assign color names to certain ranges of the spectrum, as you see fit. For example, maybe red is 0-39, orange is 40-79, etc. (those are arbitrary numbers - I have no idea if they fit on any kind of scale or not). Then calculate the hue from your RGB value (you can find a formula [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hue#Computing_hue_from_RGB), although there may be others). Once you know the hue, you know what range of the spectrum it's in, and you can give it a name.

Comment: This is the only good answer here! To find a color, the HSV and HSL color space are the only good alternative. Your code could take like 5 lines in OpenCV!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple name scheme using two qualifiers and a color name:

```
string ColorName(Color c)
{
    List<float> hues = new List<float>()
    { 0, 15, 35, 44, 54, 63, 80, 160, 180, 200, 244, 280, 350, 360};
    List<string> hueNames = new List<string>()
        { "red", "orange-red", "orange", "yellow-orange", "yellow",
          "yellow-green",   "green"  , "blue-green" , "cyan", "blue", 
          "violet", "purple", "red" };

    float h = c.GetHue();
    float s = c.GetSaturation();
    float b = (c.R * 0.299f + c.G * 0.587f + c.B *0.114f) / 256f;

    string name = s < 0.35f ? "pale " : s > 0.8f ? "vivid " : "";
    name += b < 0.35f ? "dark " : b > 0.8f ? "light " : "";
    for (int i = 0; i < hues.Count - 1; i++)
        if (h >= hues[i] && h <= hues[i+1] )
        {
            name += hueNames[i];
            break;
        }
    return name;
}
```

You can easily adapt it if you want the blues to be more differentiated etc..

Answer (score 0):

Well, Red/Green/Blue are fairly easy to identify by inspection; what range of values do you need to support?

The problem is that unless you start with a named color, it is very hard to get *back* to one; `IsNamedColor` will return false even if you create an obvious color via FromArgb.

If you only need the actual expected standard colors, you could enumerate the known colors via reflection?

```
        Color test = Color.FromArgb(255,0,0);
        Color known = (
                   from prop in typeof(Color)
                       .GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static)
                   where prop.PropertyType == typeof(Color)
                   let color = (Color)prop.GetValue(null, null)
                   where color.A == test.A && color.R == test.R
                     && color.G == test.G && color.B == test.B
                   select color)
                   .FirstOrDefault();

        Console.WriteLine(known.Name);
```

You might also be able to use this approach as a source of known colors for a more sophisticated algorithm.

Comment: full spectrum
i have byte image processing from my web cam.
http://i35.tinypic.com/2yvorau.png

Comment: A slightly simpler source of standard colours is the KnownColors enum. That way you don't have to use GetProperties etc. (Use Color.FromKnownColor.)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might be helpful:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Color color = Color.FromArgb(230, 250, 230);
        Console.WriteLine(GetDescription(color));
    }
    
    public static string GetDescription(Color color)
    {
        var hue = color.GetHue();
        var brightness = color.GetBrightness();
        var saturation = color.GetSaturation();
        
        Console.WriteLine($"H:{hue} B:{brightness} S:{saturation}");
        
        if (brightness > 95)
            return "White";
        if (brightness < 0.1 && saturation < 5)
            return "Black";
        if (hue == 0 && brightness > 0.1 && saturation < 5)
            return "Grey";
        
        if (hue > 330)
            return "Red";
        if (hue < 30)
            return "Red";
        if (hue > 30 && hue < 90)
            return "Yellow";
        if (hue > 90 && hue < 150)
            return "Green";
        if (hue > 150 && hue < 210)
            return "Cyan";
        if (hue > 210 && hue < 270)
            return "Blue";
        if (hue > 270 && hue < 330)
            return "Magenta";
        return "ND";
    }   
}
```

The idea is to associate descriptors to [hue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hue) ranges.

To cover the cases of black, white and grey it is also necessary to take into consideration the saturation and brightness (some adjustment of the limits may be necessary).