# How to get the color's name from input type="color" with C#

Tags: c#, html, input, types, colors

I have this `<input type="color" id="favcolor">`. now I want to store the color's name. I mean: red, blue, black,etc.

the value I'm getting from the `textbox` is: `#ffffff` (favcolor.text.tostring();.
related to the picked color). how can I cget the color's name?

**I want to store: red, blue, black, white .. just like that! no html code, no rgb color! I want the color's name using: C#**

by the way, I have already tried:

Color mycolor = Color.FromName("red"); then what you get is .. #FF0000 
**i want the opposite**

Comment: Check this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/365935/trying-to-convert-rgb-from-a-net-color-to-a-string-such-as-red-or-blue).

Answer (score 0):

Consider this: Color.[FromName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.color.fromname%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

**EDIT:**

```
System.Array colorsArray = Enum.GetValues(typeof(KnownColor));
KnownColor[] allColors = new KnownColor[colorsArray.Length];
Array.Copy(colorsArray, allColors, colorsArray.Length);
var colorValueToColorMap = allColors.ToDictionary(x => Color.FromName(x.ToString()).ToString().ToLower(), Color.FromName(x.ToString()));

var colorValue = "#FF0000";
var argbColorValue = "#" + "FF" +  colorValue.Substring(1);
var color = colorValueToColorMap[argbColorValue.ToLower()];
```

Comment: with that method you get the code of the color..
Color mycolor = Color.FromName("red");
then what you get is .. #FF0000 .. i want the opposite

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code, Note that only for the [known colors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.knowncolor%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) you will get the expected color name (Red,Aqua,Green).

```
Color color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#FF98FB98");
string colorName = color.Name;
```

Outputs

> ## FF32CD32 => LimeGreen
>
> ## FF00FFFF => Aqua

Comment: when i pick "red" .. the output is: Color [A=255, R=255, G=0, B=0] ..
`
Color color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml(TextBox1.Text.ToUpper().ToString());
        string colorName = color.ToString();

        Label1.Text = colorName;`

Comment: WAIT !!!!!! the text i'm getting from my textbox just have 6 digits, like #_ _ _ _ _ _ (e.g. #FF0000)

Comment: Like i said it will give you the exact color names only for KnwonColors. If you type hexadecimal color codes for other mixed colors you will not get a user friendly name.

Comment: I have updated the code, you can use color.Name property to get the exact name.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to iterate over the known colors converting them to hex code and compare for a match.

```
var colorInfo= Enum.GetValues(typeof(KnownColor))
                .Cast<KnownColor>()
                .Select(x => new { Name = x.ToString(), Color = FromKnownColor(x) })
                .FirstOrDefault(x => x.Color.ToArgb() == submittedColorArgbCode);

           return (colorInfo != null) ? colorInfo.Name:"Unknown";
```