# Add pale/vivid/light/dark before the color name depending on brightness and saturation

Tags: c#, colors

I want to get the closest color to this list:

```
static List<Color> clist = new List<Color>()
    {
        Color.Black, Color.Brown, Color.Blue, Color.Green, Color.Red, Color.Yellow,
        Color.Gray, Color.Indigo, Color.Orange, Color.Pink, Color.Turquoise, Color.White
    };
```

I am getting the closest color like this but I want to add: pale/dark/vivid/light depending on the brightness and saturation of the color:

```
        static string closestColor2(List<Color> colors, Color target)
        {
            var colorDiffs = colors.Select(n => ColorDiff(n, target)).Min(n => n);
            int x = colors.FindIndex(n => ColorDiff(n, target) == colorDiffs);
            return colors[x].ToString();
        }

        static int ColorDiff(Color c1, Color c2)
        {
            return (int)Math.Sqrt((c1.R - c2.R) * (c1.R - c2.R)
                                   + (c1.G - c2.G) * (c1.G - c2.G)
                                   + (c1.B - c2.B) * (c1.B - c2.B));
        }
```

Comment: You absolutely *must* calculate distance in an HSL or HSV color space (or, if you want to get really fancy, CIE or YUV or something). You *cannot* use the RGB color space if you want to get meaningful results. If the hue alone is not enough, use the other components, too. It is up to you what relative weights you assign to each component. Probably want to weight lightness/value higher than the others. Maybe hue next, and saturation last.

Comment: what other components? i'm pretty new in the color manipulate programming...

Comment: For HSL, the components would be Hue, Saturation, and Lightness. Just like for RGB, the components are Red, Green, and Blue. Search "color distance c#", there is a lot of prior discussion on this topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion would be to first have a list of colors. In your answer you have a small list of colors but you could also add all 141 of them if you wish later on.

So create a list of colors:

```
    //List of Colors
    static List<Color> clist = new List<Color>{
        Color.Black, Color.Brown, Color.Blue, Color.LightSteelBlue, Color.Green, Color.Red, Color.Yellow,
        Color.Gray, Color.Indigo, Color.Orange, Color.Pink, Color.Turquoise, Color.White
    };
```

And then another list with the names of the colors as you want them, with "vivid", "dark" etc..

```
    //List of Color Names
    static List<string> cnlist = new List<string>{
        "Black", "Brown", "Blue", "Pale Light Blue", "Green", "Red", "Yellow",
        "Gray", "Indigo", "Orange", "Pink", "Turquoise", "White"
    };
```

You can use these methods to find the closest color:

```
    int closestColor2(List<Color> colors, Color target) {
        var colorDiffs = colors.Select(n => ColorDiff(n, target)).Min(n => n);
        return colors.FindIndex(n => ColorDiff(n, target) == colorDiffs);
    }


    // distance in RGB space
    int ColorDiff(Color c1, Color c2) {
        return (int)Math.Sqrt((c1.R - c2.R) * (c1.R - c2.R)
                               + (c1.G - c2.G) * (c1.G - c2.G)
                               + (c1.B - c2.B) * (c1.B - c2.B));
    }
```

The method above will return the index of the closest color in the list and then you can take that same index and take the name that you specified from your list of color names. That way you can have exactly the name you want on each color and dont need to rely on an algorithm that is not 100% and since it is so few colors it would only take a small amount of time to write the names and as mentioned you would get them as you wish this way.

If you want to add all the colors that exist in Color.* you can use this method to get them:

```
private List<Color> GetAllColors() {
        var list = new List<Color>();
        var colorType = typeof(Color);
        var propInfos = colorType.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly | BindingFlags.Public);
        foreach (var propInfo in propInfos) {
            var color = Color.FromName(propInfo.Name);
            list.Add(color);
        }
        return list;
    }
```

Comment: If I want to Add a custom RGB how can I do it?

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of things to consider when comparing colors. 
But this question has already been answered.

Here you can find a solution:

[How to compare Color object and get closest Color in an Color[]?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27374550/how-to-compare-color-object-and-get-closest-color-in-an-color)

Comment: So as i understand it you already have code working to find the closest color but instead of returning a value like Color.Cyan you would something like "Light green" ?  In Color.* there are 141 colors, since the colors wont change i think i would go through the list of all those colors and set a name of each color manually. Then you can set whatever name you see fit and use that instead of the set name. I think it will be hard to make a good solution and if you set the names yourself you get them exactly as you wish.

Comment: I was thinking about something that will calculate the brightness and then depending on that either put dark vivid etc?

Comment: Color.GetBrightness()   -   https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.color.getbrightness.aspx

Comment: also... how do I know when to put light, vivid, dark... etc?

Comment: Pointing to an already posted solution is not an answer! You should nominate it for clsoing as a duplicate.

Comment: How do I nominate it?

Comment: Um, I was talking to @FSDaniel. Not even sure but you could also do it, I guess: Clicking Close and chosing Duplicate.. - As for your question you may weant to study [this post..](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27374550/how-to-compare-color-object-and-get-closest-color-in-an-color/27375621?s=1|1.0432#27375621)

Comment: If i use the hue method I need to change my whole list from RGB to hue?

Comment: Found out it was unnecessary and the hue method looks more appropiate for my needs but I still need to put "dark", "pale", "vivid" or "light".... ideas?

Comment: [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/365935/trying-to-convert-rgb-from-a-net-color-to-a-string-such-as-red-or-blue/39142758?s=1|1.1144#39142758) but note I gave you that link before already..

Comment: I found this but the thing is that it adds both names in the same time like... let's say vivid and light... and I want only 1 of them

Comment: I still think the best solution would be to just hardcode a name "Like Dark Blue" etc on all the colors (only 141 of them) and its a one time job. Or if you just work with the list of colors you entered in your question it is even less. Then you can have the correct name as you want it. And you can also just add more colors to the list with another name if you think a special color is missing.

Comment: But it looks easier to just add to the beginning of the closest color find pale dark vivid light depending on saturation..

Comment: The solution with pale/dark/vivid/light in some cases shows something like pale dark blue which is pretty confusing... how could I change to make it show only one and when it's needed?

Comment: Im not sure there is a good solution to this. And thus i am not sure why it needs to be dynamic. Since you only have a maximum of around 140 colors you can just set the name to exactly what you want and you are done. There might be a perfect solution out there but i dont know of any and the time spent on finding it where you already have a working solution (if its not good enough then let us know why) is probably better spent on something else. But if a hardcoded value of the 140 colors wont work please let us know.

Comment: So you want me to make 2 lists one with the RGB values of the Colors I want to show and one with the desired names?

Comment: I will put my suggestion as a new answer

Answer (score 0):

I found this code:

```
    string ColorName(Color c)
{
    List<float> hues = new List<float>()
    { 0, 15, 35, 44, 54, 63, 80, 160, 180, 200, 244, 280, 350, 360};
    List<string> hueNames = new List<string>()
        { "red", "orange-red", "orange", "yellow-orange", "yellow",
          "yellow-green",   "green"  , "blue-green" , "cyan", "blue", 
          "violet", "purple", "red" };

    float h = c.GetHue();
    float s = c.GetSaturation();
    float b = (c.R * 0.299f + c.G * 0.587f + c.B *0.114f) / 256f;

    string name = s < 0.35f ? "pale " : s > 0.8f ? "vivid " : "";
    name += b < 0.35f ? "dark " : b > 0.8f ? "light " : "";
    for (int i = 0; i < hues.Count - 1; i++)
        if (h >= hues[i] && h <= hues[i+1] )
        {
            name += hueNames[i];
            break;
        }
    return name;
}
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/365935/trying-to-convert-rgb-from-a-net-color-to-a-string-such-as-red-or-blue/39142758#39142758)

and I tried to implement it into your code like this:

```
static string closestColor1(List<Color> colors, Color target)
    {
        var hue1 = target.GetHue();
        var diffs = colors.Select(n => getHueDistance(n.GetHue(), hue1));
        var diffMin = diffs.Min(n => n);
        var x = diffs.ToList().FindIndex(n => n == diffMin);

        Color c = colors[x];

        float h = c.GetHue();
        float s = c.GetSaturation();
        float b = (c.R * 0.299f + c.G * 0.587f + c.B * 0.114f) / 256f;

        string name = s < 0.35f ? "pale " : s > 0.8f ? "vivid " : "";
        name += b < 0.35f ? "dark " : b > 0.8f ? "light " : "";

        name += colors[x].ToString();

        return name;
    }
```

but some solutions show sometimes both, things like: "pale dark red"/"pale dark blue" etc.. which is really confusing.. and you want to show only 1 of them... you should try something similar.. or think about how to put only 1..