# C# - Find color of a pixel

Tags: c#

I'm trying to c**alculate the color (Yellow,Blue,Green,Red)** using HSV and it's not working well because if the light is lower, the image will be more blue and gives me every color blue because Hue values are near blue.

**I was also trying to find black** if the mean of RGB has a small varation and if the values all less than 150 it's black.

```
                Color obter_cor_pixel = frame_drone.Bitmap.GetPixel((int)ponto_medio_x, (int)ponto_medio_y); //obtem cor do pixel no ponto médio
                                                                                                             //RGB para HSV                 

                Color obter_cor_circulo = frame_drone.Bitmap.GetPixel((int)ponto_medio_circulo.X, (int)ponto_medio_circulo.Y); //obtem cor do pixel no ponto médio
                                                                                                                               //RGB para HSV


                var media_obter_cor_circulo = (obter_cor_circulo.B + obter_cor_circulo.G + obter_cor_circulo.R) / 3;
                int variacao = 25;
                int valor_min = 150;
                if (((media_obter_cor_circulo - variacao <= obter_cor_circulo.B) && (media_obter_cor_circulo + variacao > obter_cor_circulo.B) &&
                    (media_obter_cor_circulo - variacao <= obter_cor_circulo.G) && (media_obter_cor_circulo + variacao > obter_cor_circulo.G) &&
                    (media_obter_cor_circulo - variacao <= obter_cor_circulo.R) && (media_obter_cor_circulo + variacao > obter_cor_circulo.R)) && (obter_cor_circulo.R <= valor_min) && (obter_cor_circulo.G <= valor_min) && (obter_cor_circulo.B <= valor_min))
                {

                    circulo_encontrado++;
                }


                float hue = obter_cor_pixel.GetHue();

                if (hue > 190 && hue < 280 /*&& hue2 > 170 && hue2 < 280*/)
                {
                    //frame_drone.Draw("Azul", ref f, new System.Drawing.Point((int)ponto_medio_x, (int)ponto_medio_y), new Bgr(Color.White)); //Escrever na imagem a cor no ponto medio                                                                                    
                    cores_dos_pontos_medios[incrementa_ponto_medio] = "Azul";
                }
                else if (hue > 70 && hue < 190 /*&& hue2 > 70 && hue2 < 170*/)
                {
                    //frame_drone.Draw("Verde", ref f, new System.Drawing.Point((int)ponto_medio_x, (int)ponto_medio_y), new Bgr(Color.White)); //Escrever na imagem a cor no ponto medio           
                    cores_dos_pontos_medios[incrementa_ponto_medio] = "Verde";
                }
                else if (hue >= 25 && hue <= 60 /*&& hue2 >= 25 && hue2 <= 60*/)
                {
                    //frame_drone.Draw("Amarelo", ref f, new System.Drawing.Point((int)ponto_medio_x, (int)ponto_medio_y), new Bgr(Color.White)); //Escrever na imagem a cor no ponto medio           
                    cores_dos_pontos_medios[incrementa_ponto_medio] = "Amarelo";
                }
                else if ((hue > 330 && hue <= 360) || hue > 0 && hue <= 20)
                {
                    //frame_drone.Draw("Vermelho", ref f, new System.Drawing.Point((int)ponto_medio_x, (int)ponto_medio_y), new Bgr(Color.White)); //Escrever na imagem a cor no ponto medio           
                    cores_dos_pontos_medios[incrementa_ponto_medio] = "Vermelho";
                }
```

I need a better approach.

Comment: You may want to have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/365935/trying-to-convert-rgb-from-a-net-color-to-a-string-such-as-red-or-blue/39142758?s=1|1.1176#39142758) finer grained color scheme.. - You may need to correct a blueish tone by a) recognizing it and b) shifting the colors..

Comment: do you know if there's a way to change the color temperature of the image? cold and warmer

Comment: The problem is that this is a video stream 30 fps. I need light code.

Comment: I only need to know if it's blue,red,yellow and green. This code works well if the light is perfect. If not it changes the color very easily.

Comment: Then you will have to measure and tune a correction.