# How to check RGB color and How do I know if this Range is green or red?

Tags: c#, colors, rgb

```
string greenImage = @"C:\Users\keti.p\Desktop\greenImage.jpg";
Bitmap bitMap = new Bitmap(greenImage);
int width = maxWidth / 2;
int height = maxHeight / 2;
Color c = bitMap.GetPixel(width, height);

Color color = Color.FromArgb(c.R, c.G, c.B);
```

I have this "color" Object,

For example, is this color green? Or is it red? or?
What a ranger in green..

Comment: Refer to [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV). RGB is not good for such tasks, so typically you would [convert](https://www.google.com/search?q=convert+rgb+hsv+c%23+site%3Astackoverflow.com) to HSV, do calculations and if you want to change something, then converting back to RGB.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/365935/trying-to-convert-rgb-from-a-net-color-to-a-string-such-as-red-or-blue/39142758?r=SearchResults&s=1|30.0405#39142758) should help..

Comment: Are you asking to find if a colour is red/green/etc. or to split all colours in different *dominant colour* regions? (the first: you will not classify intermediate colours, e.g. pink). Note: there is no exact solution: some colours will be "red" for some people and "absolutely not red" for other people, for this reason you should also specify what it is your "good enough".

Answer (score 8):

You want to check the hue of the colour using the [`GetHue`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.color.gethue?view=netframework-4.8) HSL method of the `Color` type:

```
Color a = Color.Red;
Console.WriteLine(a.GetHue()); // 0
Color b = Color.Green;
Console.WriteLine(b.GetHue()); // 120
```

I believe the numbers should correspond to this chart:

**[image: strong text]**

[Image source](http://thenewcode.com/61/An-Easy-Guide-To-HSL-Color)